# how to keep form values after validations

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms, yii

I have this form:

```
<?php echo CHtml::beginForm('','post',array('enctype'=>'multipart/form-data')); ?>
<div class="form">

<?php $form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
    'id'=>'users-form',
    'enableAjaxValidation'=>true,
)); ?>

    <p class="note">Fields with <span class="required">*</span> are required.</p>

    <?php echo $form->errorSummary($model); ?>

    <div class="row">
        <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'userName'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->textField($model,'userName',array('size'=>45,'maxlength'=>255, 'id'=>'in')); ?>
        <?php echo $form->error($model,'userName'); ?>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'password'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->passwordField($model,'password',array('size'=>45,'maxlength'=>30, 'id'=>'in')); ?>
        <?php echo $form->error($model,'password'); ?>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'firstName', array('id'=>'in0')); ?>
        <?php echo $form->textField($model,'firstName',array('size'=>45,'maxlength'=>50, 'id'=>'in1')); ?>
        <?php echo $form->error($model,'firstName'); ?>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'lastName', array('id'=>'in2')); ?>
        <?php echo $form->textField($model,'lastName',array('size'=>45,'maxlength'=>50, 'id'=>'in3')); ?>
        <?php echo $form->error($model,'lastName'); ?>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'birthDate', array('id'=>'birth0')); ?>
        <?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiDatePicker',array(
                        'name'=>'publishDate',
                        'attribute'=>'birthDate',
                        'model'=>$model,
                        'language'=>'en',
                        // additional javascript options for the date picker plugin
                        'options'=>array(
                            'showAnim'=>'fold',
                            'altFormat'=>'dd-mm-yy',
                            'dateFormat'=>'yy-mm-dd',
                        ),
                        'htmlOptions'=>array('id'=>'birth'),)); ?>
        <?php echo $form->error($model,'birthDate'); ?>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
                <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'gender', array('id'=>'in4')); ?>
                <?php echo $form->radioButton($model,'gender',array('value'=>'0', 'id'=>'in5')) . '<b id=in6 style="height:20px; color: #000666; font-size: 12pt;
                                                                                                font-weight: bold;"> Male</b><br>'; ?>
                <?php echo $form->radioButton($model,'gender',array('value'=>'1', 'id'=>'in7')) . '<b id=in8 style="height:20px; color: #000666; font-size: 12pt;
                                                                                                font-weight: bold;"> Female</b>'; ?>
                <?php echo $form->error($model,'gender'); ?>
        </div>

    <div class="row">
        <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'idCountry'); ?>
                <?php $country=Countries::model()->findAll();
                      $countryList=CHtml::listData($country, 'idCountry' , 'cntName');
                      $url = CController::createUrl('users/selectedcity');
                      echo CHtml::activeDropDownList($model,'idCountry', $countryList,
                      array('empty'=>'choose country','id' => 'idCountry','onchange' =>
                      "selectedcountry('{$url}', 'idCountry', '#name');",'style'=>'width:300px')); ?>
        <?php echo $form->error($model,'idCountry'); ?>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'idCity'); ?>
                <div id="name"></div>
                <?php echo $form->error($model,'idCity'); ?>
        </div>

    <div class="row">
        <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'securityQuestion'); ?>
        <?php $q=  Securityquestions::model()->findAll();
                      $qs=CHtml::listData($q, 'idQuestion' , 'question');
                      echo CHtml::activeDropDownList($model,'securityQuestion', $qs,array('empty'=>'Select question', 'id'=>'sec')); ?>
        <?php echo $form->error($model,'securityQuestion'); ?>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'answer'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->textField($model,'answer',array('size'=>45,'maxlength'=>255, 'id'=>'in')); ?>
        <?php echo $form->error($model,'answer'); ?>
    </div>

        <div class="row">
        <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'email'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->textField($model,'email',array('size'=>45,'maxlength'=>255, 'id'=>'in')); ?>
        <?php echo $form->error($model,'email'); ?>
    </div>

        <div class="row">
        <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'facebookAcc'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->textField($model,'facebookAcc',array('size'=>45,'maxlength'=>255, 'id'=>'in')); ?>
        <?php echo $form->error($model,'facebookAcc'); ?>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'twitterAcc'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->textField($model,'twitterAcc',array('size'=>45,'maxlength'=>255, 'id'=>'in')); ?>
        <?php echo $form->error($model,'twitterAcc'); ?>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'profilePhoto'); ?>
                <?php echo CHtml::radioButton('profile',false,array('value'=>'0')) . 
                                            '<b style="height:20px; color: #000666;
                                            font-size: 12pt; font-weight: bold;">
                                            Defalut</b><br>'; ?>
                <?php echo CHtml::radioButton('profile',false,array('value'=>'1')) . 
                                            '<b style="height:20px; color: #000666;
                                            font-size: 12pt; font-weight: bold;">
                                            Upload from here :</b>'; ?>
        <?php echo CHtml::activeFileField($model,'profilePhoto',array('width'=>45)); ?>
        <?php echo $form->error($model,'profilePhoto'); ?>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'website'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->textField($model,'website',array('size'=>45,'maxlength'=>500, 'id'=>'in')); ?>
        <?php echo $form->error($model,'website'); ?>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'telephone'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->textField($model,'telephone',array('size'=>45,'maxlength'=>200, 'id'=>'in')); ?>
        <?php echo $form->error($model,'telephone'); ?>
    </div>

    <div class="row buttons">
        <?php echo CHtml::submitButton($model->isNewRecord ? 'Create' : 'Save', array('id'=>'but')); ?>
                <?php echo CHtml::resetButton('Reset', array('id'=>'but')); ?>
    </div>

<?php $this->endWidget(); ?>

</div><!-- form -->
<?php echo CHtml::endForm(); ?>
```

and this is the action that the form belongs to:

```
$model=new Users;
                $countries=Countries::model()->findAll();
        // Uncomment the following line if AJAX validation is needed
        $this->performAjaxValidation($model);
        if(isset($_POST['Users']))
        {
                    $model->attributes=$_POST['Users'];
                    $model->userType='p';
                    $model->communityType='null';
                    $model->active=1;
                    $model->admin=0;
                    if($model->gender==0)
                        $model->gender='m';
                    else
                        $model->gender='f';
                    if(isset($_POST['profile'])){
                    if($_POST['profile']==0)
                        $model->profilePhoto='default.jpg';
                    elseif($_POST['profile']==1)
                        $model->profilePhoto=CUploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'profilePhoto');
                    }
                    if($model->save()){
                        $this->actionfiledir();
                        if(($_POST['profile'])==1)
                            $model->profilePhoto->saveAs($this->actionphotodir()."/".$model->profilePhoto);
                        Yii::app()->session['userId']=$model->idUser;
                        $this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$model->idUser));
                    }
                }

        $this->render('createp',array(
            'model'=>$model,'countries'=>$countries
        ));
            }
            else
                $this->redirect(array('site/index'));
    }

        public function actionCreatec()
    {
            if($this->actionlogged()==0||$this->actionisadmin()==1)
            {
        $model=new Users;
                $model2=new Communities; 
                $countries=Countries::model()->findAll();

        // Uncomment the following line if AJAX validation is needed
        $this->performAjaxValidation($model);
        if(isset($_POST['Users']))
        {

                    $model->attributes=$_POST['Users'];
                    $model->userType='c';
                    $model->gender='n';
                    $model->firstName='null';
                    $model->lastName='null';
                    $model->birthDate='null';
                    $model->active=1;
                    $model->admin=0;

                    if(isset($_POST['profile'])==0)
                        $model->profilePhoto='default.jpg';
                    elseif(isset($_POST['profile'])==1)
                        $model->profilePhoto=CUploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'profilePhoto');

                    if($model->save()){
                        $model2->idUser=$model->idUser;
                        $model2->admin=1;
                        $model2->save(false);
                        $this->actionfiledir();
                        if(isset($_POST['profile'])==1)
                            $model->profilePhoto->saveAs($this->actionphotodir()."/".$model->profilePhoto);
                        Yii::app()->session['userId']=$model->idUser;
                        $this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$model->idUser));
                    }
                }

        $this->render('createc',array(
            'model'=>$model,'countries'=>$countries
        ));
```

after submitting the form, if the the form have validation errors it will be returned to the user to re-fill and correct the errors, but the form didn't returned with its all values, so the selected radio button will returns not selected, and also the dropDownList of cities, so how to retain all values of the form if it not submitted?
I hope that my question is clear.

Comment: The usual strategy is to validate at the client first and not submit the form if it's not valid (but knowing that invalid forms will still be submitted sometimes). Once it submits, it will refresh. If you want to keep the values, update the form and send them back as the default values.

Answer (score 0):

Enable the validation on submit, if form has some error it will not submit the form.

```
  'clientOptions'=>array(
     'validateOnSubmit'=>true, // Required to perform AJAX validation on form submit
   ),
```

Add This value in

```
 $form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
      'id'=>'users-form',
     'enableAjaxValidation'=>true,
     'clientOptions'=>array(
         'validateOnSubmit'=>true, 
     ),
));
```

Comment: this not what I'am asking for, I want to keep the values of the form if it returned to the user due to validation errors.
so, if the user choose the country and city correctly, it must be returned choosen if the form not submitted